# Populating the comment section of a post MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a simple website that works like a social media website currently setup I have just an endless feed and I am trying to implement infinite scrolling, so post will load as the user scrolls down rather than all at once. I have decided to use a plugin called 'mongoose-paginate-v2' to help paginate the post. With this plugin comes a function called paginate. Here is my route below to the index page that is responsible for loading post.

````
router.get('/', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
    const postData = await Post.paginate({}, {
        populate: {
            path: 'author'
        },

        path: 'comments',
        populate: {
            path: 'author'

        }
    });
    let posts = postData.docs;
    res.render('posts/index', { posts })
})```
````

This works great but the author for the comments is not being populated and I am really struggling to figure out why. Each comment is being populated with an ID and even the author of the post is being populated.

PostSchema:

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    images: [
        {
            url: String,
            filename: String
        }
    ],
    description: String,
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    comments: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Comment'
        }
    ]

});

CommentSchema: 
const commentSchema = new Schema({
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    body: String
});
```

Here is an example of a post being printed to console when using console.log(postData.docs) before rendering.

```
 {
    comments: [
      60f88d735159d00015252440,
      60f88df35159d00015252465,
      60f88ff45159d000152524e8,
      60f899735159d000152526da
    ],
    _id: 60f88d645159d00015252432,
    title: 'First Post!',
    description: 'First SchwartzShare post.',
    images: [ [Object] ],
    author: {
      profileImage: [Object],
      _id: 60f759b470b59b0948f76db4,
      email: 'ihavebeenjamin@gmail.com',
      username: 'jam',
      __v: 1,
      description: '                                                                                                                                                                                 Fun and neat guy also really cool when you get to know me.                                        \r\n' +
        '                                        \r\n' +
        '                                        \r\n' +
        '                                        \r\n' +
        '                                        \r\n' +
        '                                        ',
      images: []
    },
    __v: 4
  },
```

This is how I was implementing it before and it was working perfectly.

````
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const posts = await Post.find({}).populate({
        path: 'comments',
        populate: {
            path: 'author',

        }
    }).populate('author');
    res.render('posts/index', { posts })
})```
````

Thanks so much any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for this npm library describes populate as follows:

```js
 * @param {Array|Object|String} [options.populate]
```

Can you try the following ?

```
router.get('/', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
    const postData = await Post.paginate({}, {
        populate:[
        {path: 'author'}
       {path: 'comments', select: 'author'},
    ]}
    });
    let posts = postData.docs;
    res.render('posts/index', { posts })
})
```